# Why doesn't Javascript work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript

I'm trying to use Internet Explorer to test a website, but scripts don't seem to be running. This seems like it's an issue on a lot of pages - for example, I tried going to the Acid3 page, and it said I needed to enable scripting. I checked my security options, and Active Scripting is set to enabled in the Internet zone. I saw a suggestion on a website to try running `regsvr32 jscript.dll`; I tried that as well, and as a regular user, I got the following message:

> The module "jscript.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005

When I ran that command as administrator, the registration succeeded. However, Javascript still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of IE and Windows? If you can easily reconfigure any custom settings, perhaps you can try a full reset? Also, an `sfc /scannow` might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I tried the answer by SnakeDoc but that didn't help with the Javascript issue.

Answer (score -1):

in internet explorer go to:

```
Tools --> Internet Options --> Advanced --> Click "Restore advanced settings" --> Click "Reset" --> Click "OK"
```

restart internet explorer and should be back to normal.